# How to remove an object from a collection model via a link

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add teh ability to easily add and remove 'players' from a 'group'

Group is a model that has_and belongs_to_many players. It is literally just a name with a group of players on it and a user_id to determine whose group it is.

Have the following in groups controller

```
def remove_player(player)
@group = current_user.groups.find params[:id]
@group.players.delete(player)
redirect_to @group
end
```

Have the following in the view

```
    - @group.players.each do |player|
      %tr
        %td
          = player.name
        %td 
          = link_to 'Delete', remove_player_group_path(player.id), :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-danger'
```

And have the following in routes

```
resources :groups do
member do
  post 'add_player'
  post 'remove_player'
end
```

But am getting a nil id routing error. 
Am sure this should be really simple, any ideas. Just want to be able to delete a player from a group.

Also experimented with:

```
= link_to 'Delete', :controller => "group", :action => "remove_player", :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-danger'
```

Which gives me a routing error...

Answer (score 0):

First off it looks like you have a syntax error.

This:

```
current_user.groups.find params[:id]
```

Should be:

```
current_user.groups.find(params[:id])
```

Secondly, shouldn't the path be:

```
group_remove_player_path(player.id)
```

Comment: The path seems fine. If I change it then i get a no method error. Rails seems happy enough with the syntax, am using the same on add-player and it seems to work. 
Error is
    
    No route matches {:action=>"remove_player", :controller=>"groups", :id=>nil}

Comment: I would advise using the pry debugging gem (https://github.com/pry/pry) and add `binding.pry` at the beginning of your 'remove_player' action to check that the value of 'player' and 'paramsp:id]' are in fact correct/not null. The application will stop at the binding.pry reference and you will be able to check the values of your variables in the console where the rails server is running.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend not using has_and_belongs_to_many, and instead using a fully fledged join table model.  eg

```
class Group
  has_many :group_players
  has_many :players, :through => :group_players

class GroupPlayer
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :player

class Player
  has_many :group_players
  has_many :groups, :through => :group_players
```

Now, if you want to remove a player from a group, you delete corresponding group_player record. This can also keep track of when players people joined the group, if you give player_groups the standard timestamp fields.

Having said all that, your problem might just be that you say

```
link_to 'Delete', :controller => "group", :action => "remove_player", :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-danger'
```

and it should be

```
link_to 'Delete', :controller => "groups", :action => "remove_player", :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-danger'
```

That is assuming you have groups_controller.rb, not group_controller.rb.  But, it's better to use named routes anyway, as @JellyFishBoy suggests.